# Having trouble with C++, can't cout << 100000 * 100000 correctly

Tags: c++

I can't print 100000 * 100000 when I use COUT in C++. The output was 1410065408 instead of 10000000000. How can I fix that?
Thanks!

Comment: `10000000000` is larger than an `int` you need to use a larger data type

Comment: If you enabled [compiler warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57842756/why-should-i-always-enable-compiler-warnings) you would probably have seen the problem right away.

Comment: Understood, thanks both a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value is truncated since 10000000000 is larger than the default interger type int max value (`std::numeric_limit<int>::max()`) ,

```
hex(10000000000) = 0x2540be400
hex(1410065408) =   0x540be400
```

You can see that the first byte is truncated.

To fix it:

```
100000LL * 100000
```

or cast it

```
static_cast<int64_t>(100000) * 100000
```

Answer (score 5):

By default, integer literals are of type `int` which causes the overflow you have.
Use `100000LL` to mark the number as `long long` and have a long long result.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal

Comment: paradocslover is not a factual sentence, but yours is. Anyways,  i found the answer on your profile. So nvm

Comment: The best discussion that i have had on SO so far :lol: